# GAE query filters one model field but not another

Tags: python, google-app-engine

please help me on this one because I'm really starting to hate GAE. I am new to it and have to bite code after someone else.
I have a model like:

```
from google.appengine.api import search

class Recipe(someModelClass):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    title_normalized = db.StringProperty()
```

Now when i run:

```
search.Index(name='GLOBAL_RECIPES').search(query=search.Query("title: pâte"))
```

I get a recipe for "pâte" (what ever it is - some french food :) )
But for the example "pâte" is normalized to "pate" and i want to query over `title_normalized`:

```
search.Index(name='GLOBAL_RECIPES').search(query=search.Query("title_normalized: pate"))
```

It returns nothing.
I'm 100% sure i have the "pâte - pate" object in my database.
My index.yaml file have no entries that would contain `kind: recipe` and `name: title` or `name: title_normalized`.
If it helps unitTests have the same query results.
Is there a place for defining fields that should be indexed?

Comment: All properties are indexed unless you specifically mark them unindexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two services here: [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) and [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/).

The model you define is a Datastore NDB model, the query you perform is a Search API query.

Comment: Very deep code digging I had and found my solution. Your answer guided me well. Thank You!